# Android studio install

Tags: android-studio

I today have started install new Android studio.
All successful finished.
But When I click on Android SDK manager icon I get This error

> **Blockquote**

```
 ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program

 C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified: Cannot run program 

C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help me!!

Comment: Try running studio with admin privileges.

Comment: I have tried, but don't help.

Comment: Does this exist: `"C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat"` ?

Comment: The `Users` directory is not a good place for IDE projects and SDKs because it requires admin privileges to write to any directory under it. But since you are already setup to use that path, simply try launching Android Studio as administrator by right-clicking on android studio and selecting `Run as Administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem
i downloaded a stand alone sdk manager and extracted it and copied tools folder to my android studio sdk folder
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools